# JAXB XML serialization error with namespace QName exception

Tags: java, jaxb, jetty, jersey

I have a [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) Service which serialises an object via JAXB to an XML representation. In worked find on Glassfish before, but after switching to Jetty I am getting a

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.xml.namespace.QName

error. When I am searching for this kind of error, I am not getting really helpful information in the web. Because it worked with Glassfish before I am little confused. Do you have an idea?

### The Jersey Part

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public DocResult returnInfo(Document dom) {

    DocResult result = new DocResult();
    List<mypackage.Document> docs = ...; // loads some documents
    result.documents = docs;
    return result;
}
```

### The class to serialize

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DocResult {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "documents")
    @XmlElement(name = "document")
    public List<Document> documents;

    public DocResult() {
        documents = new ArrayList<Document>();
    }
}
```

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.xml.namespace.QName
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.attWildcardAsURIs(XMLSerializer.java:769)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeURIs(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:395)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:344)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:597)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.JSONMarshallerImpl.marshal(JSONMarshallerImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:157)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: simply you posted the error message.without see source code how others help? atleast post part of the  source code for your getting error message?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Forgot about this. ;) I added some code parts. Thanks ILLA.